# Date Type Mysmatch in a Counter

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion

I am designing a Pre sequencing VBA code that must seek the value introduced in a row (In this case the row Z starting in Z4 and ending in Z15) and must verify if it already exists in another row (in this case the row AC starting in AC4 and ending in AC15). If it does not exist it must place the time in the corresponding cell of the row AC (e.g. Z4 --> AC4, Z5 --> AC5). This is a way in which I assure that no AC cell contains a value equal to another AC value (understand the AC values as places in a row with two minutes of difference). If it finds the value of the Z row in the AC row, it must add two minutes to the Z value and check again if that "place" is already taken, until it founds a free place.

In the code below you can see the example for the cell Z4, that will be a repititive statement for each Z in the row.

It runs the counter Nº4 perfectly, but as soon as it gives the counter Nº5, in the line 'ActualHour=CDate(Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(Counter, 29))' It brings the ‘Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch’. I do not know why because the type is still the same, and the values too, I attach images of the counter 4 and 5: [Counter4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzqRM.png) [Counter5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVxu0.png)

```
Sub TSAT4()
    Dim DesiredHour As Date
    Dim HourTaken As Boolean
    Dim ActualHour As Date
    HourTaken = True
    DesiredHour = CDate(Range("Z4"))
    Do While HourTaken = True
        HourTaken = False
        For Counter = 4 To 15
            ActualHour = CDate(Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(Counter, 29))
                If CDate(ActualHour) = DesiredHour Then DesiredHour = DateAdd("n", 2, DesiredHour) And HourTaken = True
            Next Counter
    Loop
Sheets("Hoja1").Range("AC4") = DesiredHour
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Debug.Print TypeName(Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(Counter, 29).Value)` - what is the result?

Comment: It brough the word Empty in the first counter (Counter Nº4), which is logical, and String in the Counter Nº5... Why?

Comment: What is the value in that cell?

Comment: The one you can see in the two images added above (each one in each counter) #0:00:00# ; Type: Date... That is why it sounds weird to me, it works the first time but not the second one.

Comment: No - the value in that cell, not the value of `ActualHour`.

Comment: If you mean in the cell... it is a formula!! maybe there is the mistake, the previuos one isnt

Comment: And what is the formula and its value?

Comment: There was no need of the formula, it was removed and it worked, but now I face the second and last problem, in the second cell, Z5, whenever I introduce the same value it does not add two minutes with the DateAdd, it just settles (0:00:00)...

Comment: you have to separate `Then DesiredHour = DateAdd("n", 2, DesiredHour) And HourTaken = True` into `Then - DesiredHour = DateAdd("n", 2, DesiredHour) - HourTaken = True - End If` where hyphens stand for new line

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly, I really appreciate your help, I have been thinking on this for a time.